# BIM 360 model properties API returning forbidden (projects/:projectId/diffs:batch-status)

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

We are trying to initiate the diff(comparison) process between two versions of a model uploaded over the BIM 360 platform using BIM 360-provided APIs https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/index-v2-diff-jobs-batch-status-post/ .
We are getting forbidden error as given in attached image
We cross-checked the credentials, tokens, configurations, and scopes(using internal tokens with scopes DataRead,
ViewablesRead, DataWrite, DataCreate) multiple times. All seems to be correct. Still, we are facing these issues.

[Attached error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vh9C0.png)

Any help will appreciated

Comment: as replying in the private email, I can reproduce this issue. I am checking with engineer team.

Comment: this issue has been fixed. It was a problem with the API authentication mechanism, Sorry for the issue. thank you for telling us it works back now.

Comment: thank you !! @XiaodongLiang for your response